# C++ BSON Library how to load bson from c_str()?

Tags: c++, json, mongodb, bson

Say we have a string with binary bson data inside. How to load it into [bson object](http://www.mongodb.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=16646453)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's an example to do just that on that same page:

```
BSONObjBuilder b;
b << "name" << "Joe" << "age" << 33;
BSONObj p = b.obj();
```

That is, `BSONObjBuilder` has a stream operator for `const char *`.

[From the docs](http://api.mongodb.org/cplusplus/current/classmongo_1_1_b_s_o_n_obj_builder.html):

```
BSONObjBuilderValueStream & operator<< (const char *name)
Stream oriented way to add field names and values.
```

Comment: I meant I already have bson generated by someone (it was downloaded into some std::string), now I want to parse it into object using bson, and wonder how to do such thing?

Comment: You want to construct a BSONObj or you want to extract the data fields?

Comment: Why can't you just pass the string to 
mongo::BSONObj::BSONObj ( const char *  msgdata )

Comment: It only works for raw bson - it just assigns to
    `const char *_objdata;`

Comment: is it possible to feed raw json to it?

Answer (score 1):

try BSONObj p(you_data_pointer);

Answer (score 0):

For raw json string use **mongo::fromjson**

```
mongo::BSONObj object = mongo::fromjson("{"Login":"test","Password":"12345","Role":["admin","manager"]}");
```